# Magento Enterprise Licence - Does it include SQL Cluster?

Tags: mysql, magento

Trying to Evaluate Magento for an E-commerce solution. I have a naive question regarding the licence (Interestingly Magento Sales North America is not able to get me an answer, since i haven't bought licence yet, i cant raise this question under technical support either). So the Question is

Does Enterprise Edition comes with a MYSQL Cluster licence also or should i procure that MySQL cluster licence separately. I know it supports MySQL cluster in Enterprise Version but does the Licence include cluster license too is the question.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spoke with our sales team and the MySQL cluster license is not included.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Magento and their licenses.
With MySQL there is a MySQL Cluster Carrier Grade Edition
that gives you access to MySQL Cluster.
The MySQL Enterprise Edition does not.

Answer (score 0):

Magento just confirmed that we need to procure separate licence for SQL Cluster if we need support.